# Using String replace to create a query with date problem

Tags: java, string, date

I am trying to create a string query in Java in a dynamic way since parameters change. I am using the replace() method in order to attach parameters, however, I am having trouble when it comes to Java dates.

When using "replace" it expects a string, since date is not a string I am converting it to a string.

I have tried this:

Query example:

String query =

```
(formId = formId and rate = rateId and validityDate <= eventDate and creationDate >= eventDate)
```

```
query = query.replace("formId", input.getFormId.toString());
query = query.replace("rateId ", input.getrateId.toString());
query = query.replace("eventDate", input.geteventDate.toString());
```

This seems to work find apart from the date which SQL does not except this way.

I also have tried converting date to SQL date and using SimpleDateFormat, but I have the same problem.

What is the best way to pass a date from an object into a string query?

Comment: If this is for SQL, you shouldn't be replacing strings, you should be working with a prepared statement.

Comment: I'd say that almost any query language supports placeholders and a way of setting parameter values with automatic conversion of standard types like dates (and I hope we're talking java.time here). SQL prepared statements would be like `"... validityDate <= ? ..."` and the placeholder is referenced by position which would be 3 in your example, JPA's JPQL would make this `"... validityDate <= :eventDate ...`" and then you set the parameter by its name `"eventDate"`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a sql/jdbc query?

If so you shouldn't be doing string replacements because this could open your app to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Instead you should do something like

```java
try (Connection con = connectionSource.getConnection()) {
   PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from foo where formId = ? and rateId = ? and validityDate <= ? and creationDate >= ?");
   ps.setLong(1, formId);
   ps.setLong(2, rateId);
   ps.setTimestamp(3, eventDate);
   ps.setTimestamp(4, eventDate);
   ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
   while (rs.next()) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Please see XKCD's comic related to SQL injection attacks https://xkcd.com/327/

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try this out and let you know!

Comment: I have a question tho. lets say I have to run this over a loop and create a long string query, should I still use preparedStatement?

Comment: Correct and good. Except since JDBC 4.2 do not use `setTimestamp()` and `Timestamp`. Use `ps.setObject()` and pass a `LocalDate`, `OffsetDateTime` or other date-time type from java.time (the modern Java date and time API since 2014) as appropriate for the SQL type.

Comment: *lets say I have to run this over a loop and create a long string query, should I still use preparedStatement?* Yes, most certainly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer for the follow up question

> I have a question tho. lets say I have to run this over a loop and create a long string query, should I still use preparedStatement?

When you have complex where clauses, I tend to do something like

```java
public interface ParameterSetter {
   void apply(PreparedStatement ps, int index) throws SQLException;
}
```

```
public List<Person> findPeopleByFilter(PersonFilter filter) {
   List<String> whereClauses = new ArrayList<>();
   List<ParameterSetter> paramSetters = new ArrayList<>();
   if (filter.getAge() != null) {
      whereClauses.add("age = ?");
      paramSetters.add((ps, i) -> ps.setInt(i, filter.getAge());
   }
   if (filter.getName() != null) {
      whereClauses.add("name = ?");
      paramSetters.add((ps, i) -> ps.setString(i, filter.getName());
   }

   // any number of extra where clauses (and their ParameterSetters) are determined here

   String sql = "SELECT * FROM PERSON";
   if (!whereClauses.isEmpty()) {
      sql += " WHERE " + whereClauses.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" AND "));
   }

   try (Connection con = getConnection()) {
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      int index = 1;
      for (ParameterSetter paramSetter : paramSetters) {
         paramSetter.apply(ps, index++);
      }
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
      List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
      while (rs.next()) {
         ...
      }
      return people;
   }
}
```